# How to change the Explorer in VS Code to have angular js icons

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

What is the required addon on procedure in order to apply specific icons in to Explorer in VS Code.

[image: How to change the Explorer Icons like this]

[image: Current Project]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this icon pack from the vscode marketplace

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons

After that you have to apply the new icons

File > Preferences > File Icon Theme > VSCode Icons

Or on MacOS

Code > Preferences > File Icon Theme > VSCode Icons

Edit:

If you want to make your own icon pack you can look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10804)

Comment: Worked. Thanks. :D